# How to test request.resource.data.field is equal to request.auth.field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I'm trying to test a simple rule using `@firebase/rules-unit-testing (^2.0.7)` but the docs say uid is no longer supported [(see)](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/ce6189631fad4c4d1fd4a0f0b3a404e9726da0dc/packages/util/src/emulator.ts#L101).

The rule is simply allowing the write of a comment only when its user access to it;

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /comments/{docId} {
      allow write: if request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

And my only test with setup looks like this;

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const {
  assertFails,
  assertSucceeds,
  initializeTestEnvironment,
  RulesTestEnvironment,
} = require('@firebase/rules-unit-testing');

let testEnv;

beforeAll(async () => {
  const rules = readFileSync('firestore.rules', 'utf8');
  
  testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
    projectId: 'demo-test',
    firestore: {
      rules,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8080,
    },
  });
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await testEnv.cleanup();
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  await testEnv.clearFirestore();
});

describe('Comments rules', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await testEnv.withSecurityRulesDisabled(context => {
      const firestoreWithoutRule = context.firestore()
      return firestoreWithoutRule
        .collection('comments')
        .add({ userId: 1, text: 'all good' })
    });
  });

  it('', async () => {
    const updateByAuthenticatedUser = testEnv
      .authenticatedContext(1)
      .firestore()
      .collection('comments')
      .doc('1')
      .update({ userId: 1, text: 'all bad' });

    await assertSucceeds(updateByAuthenticatedUser);
  });
});
```

How can I make this work?

(this question is mostly code because the minimum reproducible example happens to be this much code, this is boilerplate writing just for updating the question)

Comment: Have you confirmed that `v2.0.7` is the version you have installed? You can do this in-code by checking the output of `console.log(require('@firebase/rules-unit-testing').CONSTANTS.SDK_VERSION)`. The [source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/%40firebase/rules-unit-testing%402.0.7/packages/rules-unit-testing/src/impl/test_environment.ts#L48-L58) shows that it should be using `sub` already.

Comment: Alternatively, in the case that something weird is going on, you can try `.authenticatedContext(1, { uid: undefined })` to force the guard you linked to fail.